# How to add and use a jar library in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: jpa, intellij-idea, jar, openjpa

I created a new Java app from scratch in IntelliJ IDEA. Now I want to use a jar library, e.g. OpenJPA. I added the library using `Project Structure` -> `Libraries` like this:

[image]

then I tried to use annotations from that library in my Java code, but I don't get the option to import these classes. It looks like IntelliJ IDEA is not known about my library yet:

[image]

What am I doing wrong when adding this library? Is there anything more that I have to do to get it working?

---

After adding this library, it looks like it is automatically added to "Modules":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a library, but you haven't said IntelliJ that the module must use it. Click *Modulesµ in the project structure, then select the module you want to add this library to, go to the *Dependencies* tab, and add the library.

EDIT:

It's simply that the annotation is not part of the jar. You need to add the jpa api jar, not only openjpa.jar

Comment: It looks like it is added there automatically. See my updated picture.

Comment: OK, then it's simply that the annotation is not part of the jar. You need to add the jpa api jar, not only openjpa.jar.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks, that worked. Please add it as an update to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add library to Module dependencies, pls check here:
[Configuring Module Dependencies and Libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html)

Comment: It looks like it is added there automatically. See my updated picture.